# Getting "Integrity constraint violation (Duplicate entry for key)" in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table that I have recently edited to add another index using two columns (which combined are required to be unique).

The problem is now I get an error when I go to create a new model record:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry ... for key ....

The two columns are titled:

- shipment_origin
- pro_number

So as an example, the end result would look like: 1-230185

And I have checked, the record is created technically, it just doesn't follow through and the error is returned. So to make it simple, there is no record before hand (so there's no duplicate entry), a record is created in the database and the error is returned (no matter what).

Or is there a way to go about doing this directly through Laravel rather than MySQL?

### Update

Here is the public function in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate(request(), [

            'pro_number' => 'required',
            'shipment_origin' => 'required'
            /*'piecesNumber' => 'required' (had to remove for now, but must review)*/

        ]);

        $user_id = Auth::id();

        $input = $request->all();

        //Save Initial Shipment Data
        $shipment = new Shipment();
        $shipment->pro_number = request('pro_number');
        $shipment->shipment_origin = request('shipment_origin');
        $shipment->date = request('date');
        $shipment->due_date = request('due_date');
        $shipment->tractor_id = request('tractor_id');
        $shipment->trailer_id = request('trailer_id');
        $shipment->driver_id = request('driver_id');
        $shipment->notes = request('notes');
        $shipment->shipper_no = request('shipper_no');
        $shipment->ship_to = request('ship_to');
        $shipment->ship_from = request('ship_from');
        $shipment->bill_to = request('bill_to');
        $shipment->bill_type = request('bill_type');
        $shipment->load_date = request('load_date');
        $shipment->shipment_status = 1;
        $shipment->shipment_billing_status = (isset($request->shipment_billing_status) && !empty($request->shipment_billing_status)) ? $request->shipment_billing_status : 1;
        $shipment->created_by = $user_id;
        $shipment->cn_billtoName = request('cn_billtoName');
        $shipment->cn_billtoAddress1 = request('cn_billtoAddress1');
        $shipment->cn_billtoAddress2 = request('cn_billtoAddress2');
        $shipment->cn_billtoCity = request('cn_billtoCity');
        $shipment->cn_billtoState = request('cn_billtoState');
        $shipment->cn_billtoZip = request('cn_billtoZip');
        $shipment->cn_billtoEmail = request('cn_billtoEmail');
        $shipment->cn_billtoPhone = request('cn_billtoPhone');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoName = request('cn_shiptoName');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoAddress1 = request('cn_shiptoAddress1');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoAddress2 = request('cn_shiptoAddress2');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoCity = request('cn_shiptoCity');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoState = request('cn_shiptoState');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoZip = request('cn_shiptoZip');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoEmail = request('cn_shiptoEmail');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoPhone = request('cn_shiptoPhone');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromName = request('cn_shipfromName');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromAddress1 = request('cn_shipfromAddress1');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromAddress2 = request('cn_shipfromAddress2');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromCity = request('cn_shipfromCity');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromState = request('cn_shipfromState');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromZip = request('cn_shipfromZip');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromEmail = request('cn_shipfromEmail');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromPhone = request('cn_shipfromPhone');
        $shipment->fuelChargeDesc = request('fuelChargeDesc');
        $shipment->fuelChargeAmt = request('fuelChargeAmt');
        $shipment->fuelChargeTotal = request('fuelChargeTotal');
        $shipment->permitChargeDesc = request('permitChargeDesc');
        $shipment->permitChargeAmt = request('permitChargeAmt');
        $shipment->permitChargeTotal = request('permitChargeTotal');
        $shipment->otherChargeDesc = request('otherChargeDesc');
        $shipment->otherChargeAmt = request('otherChargeAmt');
        $shipment->otherChargeTotal = request('otherChargeTotal');
        $shipment->noCharge = request('noCharge');
        $shipment->noSettle = request('noSettle');
        $shipment->Total = request('Total');
        if ((request('shipment_billing_status') == 2) || (request('shipment_billing_status') == 3)){
           $balance = 0.00;
        }else{
           $balance = request('Total');
        }
        $shipment->Balance = $balance;
        $shipment->freightBillSubtotal = request('freightBillSubtotal');

        $shipment->save();

        //Save Shipment Details

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->shipment_details['piecesNumber']); $i++) {
            //the first line used to be 'shipment_id' => $shipment->pro_number,
            Shipment_Detail::create([
                'shipmentID' => $shipment->id, 
                'pieces_number' => $request->shipment_details['piecesNumber'][$i],
                'pieces_type' => $request->shipment_details['piecesType'][$i],
                'rate_type' => $request->shipment_details['rateType'][$i],
                'charge' => $request->shipment_details['charge'][$i],
                'weight' => $request->shipment_details['weight'][$i],
                'hazmat' => $request->shipment_details['hazmat'][$i],
                'description' => $request->shipment_details['description'][$i] ]);
        }

        $carrier = \App\Customer::where('carrier','=',1)->get();
        foreach($carrier as $car){
                        $carrierUsers = $car->users;
                        if ($carrierUsers->count() > 0){
                            foreach($carrierUsers as $carrierUser){
                                $carrierUser->notify(new FreightBillNew($shipment));
                            }
                }
                }  

        Session::flash('success_message','Freight Bill Successfully Created'); //<--FLASH MESSAGE

        //Return to Register//
        return redirect('/shipments/accounts');

    }
```

Comment: Are you bulk inserting or just doing one create/insert when this error occurs?

Comment: At this time, and I doubt it will change, I am only inserting one record at a time.

Comment: Post the code that does the record creation.

Comment: @btl - I have added my function to the post. I will make the note that prior to my addition of the this index/key, this worked fine so I know it has something to do with this addition... Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible you are creating another shipment record somewhere else in this process? Such as in this notification `$carrierUser->notify(new FreightBillNew($shipment));`? You say a record is created so it must be getting here ` $shipment->save();`. Does the redirect happen or is the exception thrown before?

Comment: Can you show us your `shipments migration`?

Comment: This looks like it has been abandoned without an [mcve], so can be put on hold for now.